# Passing big multi-dimensional array to function in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, argument-passing

I'm having trouble passing a big array to a function in C.

I declare:

```
int image[height][width][3]={};
```

where height and width can be as big as 1500. And when I call:

```
foo((void *)image,height,width);
```

which is declared as follows:

```
int *foo(const int *inputImage, int h, int w);
```

I get segmentation fault error. What's strange is that if my values are:

```
height=1200;
width=290;
```

theres no problem, but when they're:

```
height=1200;
width=291;
```

i get the mentioned error. At 4 bytes per integer with both height and width of 1500 (absolute worst case) the array size would be of 27MB which imo isn't that big and shouldn't really matter because I'm only passing a pointer to the first element of the array. Any advice?

Comment: Is `image` on the stack?  If so, you're almost certainly running out of space on the stack.  Try dynamically allocating the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 27 MB, your array is probably bigger than the stack, which is usually 1 MB. You are corrupting your process as soon as `foo` starts working with the data. Allocate the array on the heap instead:

```
typedef int (*image_buf)[height][width][3];
image_buf image = malloc(sizeof(image_buf));
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. I'll read some more, because I still can't see why passing a pointer to the first element overflows the stack.

Comment: @kirbuchi: The stack is used for local variables.  You're overflowing the stack not by passing the pointer, but rather by trying to define such a large local array.  I imagine it's simply not erroring until you try to access an element that is past your stack space... which occurs in your foo() function.

Comment: I did some reading and I think I get it now. Turns out stack space is used for local variables, so when calling foo() it tries to allocate the 27MB on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the default process stack size using 'ulimit -a' on unix systems

```
   (blocks, -c) 0
```

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 20
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16382
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: While that's true, passing a large amount of data as an array by value is horribly bad for performance. It's better to allocate memory on the heap and pass a pointer to that, than to increase the stack size just so you can copy 27MB of data onto the stack for a function argument...